# Frequency of Correlation Between Two Categorical Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, categorical-data, pairwise

I have two Pandas dataframes, with each unique member_id potentially having numerous rows that list their cars owned and pets owned, respectively. The two DFs have thousands of rows each and their structures look like this (this is a super abstract example because I'm not at liberty to share what categorical variables I'm actually comparing. The main point is that there are two categorical variables that each member can have multiple of, and it's known that there is likely correlation between at least *some* of pairs of cars/pets):

[image: Cars and Pets DFs]

My goal is to look at the pair-wise correlation between *every* pair of pet and car. For example, from the image pinned above, out of the three members who own a cat (2, 3, and 4), one of them owns a Toyota. Therefore, the pairwise frequency for Cat-Toyota would be 33%. This is quite easy to do with a small set of data, but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to automate this on thousands of rows. Particularly, since each member can have numerous rows in both the dataframes, I can't figure out how to group by member and then iterate over each pet-car combination for that member.

Comment: Please, dont upgrade images as code. Pasting as text increases your chances of having an answer. Feel free to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Terry How do I upload the DF as text? I have yet to be able to figure that out and that link doesn't seem to have the answer

Comment: you can copy the result of `df.head()` as example and paste as "code sample" on edit menu

Answer (score 0):

First of all created some random data (good point for next time post easy to copy data sample):

```
from random import choices
import pandas as pd

member_ids = [1,2,3,4]
pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'snake', 'lion', 'platypus', 'bat', 'pangolin']
cars = ['toyota', 'ford', 'fiat', 'maserati', 'ferrari']

df = pd.DataFrame([choices(member_ids, k=200), choices(pets, k=200), choices(cars, k=200)], index=['id', 'pet', 'car']).T.drop_duplicates()
```

Then, if I understand correctly what you want, use groupby and value counts normalized:

```
df.groupby('pet')['car'].value_counts(normalize=True).round(3)
```